# ANSIBLE - Answer yes no to questions

Tags: ansible, prompt

I am working on a playbook that will upgrade an app I have. Part of that upgrade means that I get asked a question.

Ideally I would like to be able to answer yes / no to these questions and not have to do any sort of pause or prompt for user input.

From what I have read online it is definitely possible but I cannot seem to get it to work for me.

Here is my code:

```
  - name: Upgrade
    expect:
      command: /tmp/bin/update_script.sh 
      environment:
        JAVA_HOME: /opt/java/
      responses:
        Question:
          - Do you want to use the standard cipher suites [N]: n
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the versions of the code you tried and the actual output, neatly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

This done what i needed .. Unfortunately it does not allow you answer yes / no but it gets the job done for now.

It would have been nice to have more control but its works as a temp workaround for now .. When I have a permanent solution I will post again.

```
  - name: Upgrade Starting
    shell: |
      yes | /tmp/bin/update_script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your response types. If you provide a list, it doesn't want/need the question. If you want to specifically match questions to responses, use a regex to match the question as the key of a dictionary.

So, version 1:

```
- name: Upgrade
  expect:
    command: /tmp/bin/update_script.sh 
    environment:
      JAVA_HOME: /opt/java/
    responses:
      Question:
        - n
```

or version 2 (check my regex*):

```
- name: Upgrade
  expect:
    command: /tmp/bin/update_script.sh 
    environment:
      JAVA_HOME: /opt/java/
    responses:
      Question:
        cipher: n
```

I have used expect, but not the ansible module, and it was years ago, and I never used it much. Hopefully this will work as-is either way, but be prepared to twiddle with it. ;)

Good luck!

Comment: No joy, it just does not want to pick up the question it is asking

Do you want to use the new default (disable weaker cipher suites)? (y/n)

Comment: you tried just passing the `n` as a list without the question? Or is that not an option?

Comment: If i try either option above it just spits out the question and fails  ...... Do you want to use the new default (disable weaker cipher suites)? (y/n) "]} ......... Very strange

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass the answer to the question as a variable using extra_variables. This will avoid the prompt and allow you to set the variable to some default value as well.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/release.yml --extra-vars 'updateciphers=True updatedcipherslist=["cipher1","cipher2","cipher3"]'
```

-> You may need to escape the double quotes.
    vars:
     updateciphers: False

```
tasks:
  - name: Upgrade
    command: /tmp/bin/update_script.sh 
    environment:
      JAVA_HOME: /opt/java/
    when: updateciphers
    with_items: "{{ updatedcipherslist }}"
```

Comment: seems to be just to complicated .. i am going to try this

  - name: Upgrade Starting
      command: yes | /tmp/bin/update_script.sh

Comment: See the [notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html). `If you want to run a command through the shell (say you are using <, >, |, etc), you must specify a shell in the command such as /bin/bash -c "/path/to/something | grep else".` Also, `The expect module is designed for simple scenarios. For more complex needs, consider the use of expect code with the shell or script modules.` An example is part of the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module) module documentation. If you do you can say `yes no | ...` - fun! :)

Comment: this works, just a shame i cant have more control, its ok for tis time but sometimes i may have 3 questions to answer and i might not want to always answer yes
shell: |
      yes | /tmp/bin/update_script.sh